# How do I call a model in a controller?

Tags: model, getmodel

This is the content of my controller:

```
<?php
class Attin_Exportdb_Adminhtml_AttributesController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action{

    public function IndexAction() {

        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock("head")->setTitle($this->__("Export Attributes"));

        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Mage_Core_Block_Template','attributes_exp_db',array('template' => 'exportdb/attributes.phtml'));
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);

        $this->renderLayout(); 

    }
    public function AjaxAction(){

        $model = Mage::getModel('exportdb/attrdb')->query_attr();
        echo $model;
    }
}
```

This is the content of my model:

```
<?php

class Attin_Export_Model_Attrdb extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{

   public function query_attr(){
        return "Test";
   }

}
```

and this is the config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Attin_Exportdb>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Attin_Exportdb>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <exportdb>
                <class>Attin_Exportdb_Helper</class>
            </exportdb>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <exportdb>
                <class>Attin_Exportdb_Block</class>
            </exportdb>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <exportdb>
                <class>Attin_Exportdb_Model</class>
            </exportdb>
        </models>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <attin_exportdb before="Mage_Adminhtml">Attin_Exportdb_Adminhtml</attin_exportdb>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

My question in AjaxAction() function what am I doing wrong ? thx in advance

Comment: Thx a lot for both of you !!!

Comment: Please dont make a question updation based on the answer given here unless it was an error when you prepare the question.It will ruin the intergrity of the answer. You can edit the content and "beautify" it ofcourse. Hope you will understand.

Comment: yes, sure, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the your configuration , your model class name is wrong. It should be `Attin_Exportdb_Model_Attrdb` instead of `Attin_Export_Model_Attrdb`

### More Details

Your configuration is looks like this

```
   <models>
        <exportdb>
            <class>Attin_Exportdb_Model</class>
        </exportdb>
    </models>
```

So when you call a model like this `Mage::getModel('exportdb/someModel')`, then Magento first trace which module holds `exportdb` as its model alias name. In this case Magento will find `Attin_Exportdb`.

Now Magento will trace the model location from `<class>` node. So in your case it is `Attin_Exportdb_Model`.

Again Magento uses `someModel` in order to generate the rest class name. In this case it will append to the previous value. So the class that magento expects become `Attin_Exportdb_Model_SomeModel` and Magento expects this class in the location

```
 app/code/<codePool>/Attin/Exportdb/Model/SomeModel.php
```

Comment: Thx a lot , my mistake !!!

Comment: Don't think he's suggesting change from `Exportdb` to `Export`, he's pointing out that in your question the class name uses just `Export`

Comment: @JonathanHussey: I gave a description.

Answer (score 6):

There are issue in 
**Issue 1:**

`<model>` should be  `<models>` .It magento logic .please check at config.xml

So

```
<model>
            <exportdb>
                <class>Attin_Exportdb_Model</class>
            </exportdb>
        </model>
```

Should be

```
<models>
            <exportdb>
                <class>Attin_Exportdb_Model</class>
            </exportdb>
        </models>
```

**Issue2:**

Also your issue in model class name  it should be

`Attin_Exportdb_Model_Attrdb` instead of `Attin_Export_Model_Attrdb` As you module dir is

Attin_Exportdb which define at config.xml

```
 <Attin_Exportdb> <!-- this path of module -->
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Attin_Exportdb>
```

Please check how to  Call model and block and create an extension

http://www.amitbera.com/create-an-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table/

Comment: Yup, everything else looks fine.

Comment: I changed to models, but I still get this error message: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function query_attr() on a non-object in <b>/home/netlogiq/public_html/CUSTOM/attin/ef/app/code/local/Attin/Exportdb/controllers/Adminhtml/AttributesController.php</b> on line <b>19</b><br />

Comment: Have you cleared the cache after changing?

Comment: @Amit Bera Thx a lot